# Tradingview snapshot feature; pulling request get with python to execute and grab url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, request, python-requests

[image: example xhr response]

I am trying to use Python 3.6 to access the snapshot feature of tradingview to get the url created. I was able to use selenium and be successful but it was taking along 4 seconds to execute. I was hoping to use requests library to achieve this.

First of; is this even possible? url is https://s.tradingview.com/widgetembed/?symbol=DRYS. There is a little camera on the right side. The html scraper cant be used since the url is generated after pressing the snapshot icon.

Any pointers can help.